# Some questions about webapi ActionFilterAttribtes, FilterProvider, and Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api

I see that by default, an MVC4 WebApi project has 2 `IFilterProviders`: The `ConfigurationFilterProvider`, and the `ActionDescriptorFilterProvider`. When setting up a custom `IFilterProvider` to do property depenency injection, is it appropriate to remove both of these from the Filters collection first? Or is it more appropriate to just remove the `ActionDescriptorFilterProvider`, and leave the `ConfigurationFilterProvider` in the collection?

Secondly, I see that after a WebApi Http `ActionFilterAttribute` is constructed for a particular action, it seems to stay around. For example when I put a custom action filter on an ApiController Get method, it is only constructed the first time that method is called. Subsequent calls to the api method seem to reuse the same filter (constructor breakpoints are only hit during the first invocation). Is this right? Why is it different than an MVC actionfilter, where a new instance is created for each method invocation?

Comment: did you ever find out why your action filters where only getting instantiated once? I am experiencing the same problem(?) where my actions filters are acting as singletons.

Comment: @Paul, no I did not. Perhaps you could offer a bounty on the second part of my question.

Comment: Decided to do a little research and it turns out every annotation acts as a singleton. So if you annotate a Controller and an Action with the same Attribute, they will both be constructed a single time and then reused on subsequent requests. My confusion stems from a MVC4 project I was helping a friend with that was using Autofac and the Attributes were getting constructed on each request. strange, really.

Answer (score 1):

> is it appropriate to remove both of these from the Filters collection first?

I have been successful in implementing dependency injection on Action Filters without removing either of these FilterProviders. Infact, I am extending the `ActionDescriptorFilterProvider` in my example using StructureMap.

http://evolutionarydeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/webapi-actionfilter-dependency.html

I cannot shed any light on your second question I'm afraid :-)

Comment: in your blog article you create a SmFilterProvider class but don't say how to register it?  I tried with GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add but the class doesn't implement IFilter.  Can you help me understand how to register the class instance with the framework?

Comment: I think you have two options. The line in the blog that you can use is from the last example: `cfg.For<IFilterProvider>().Use<SmFilterProvider>();`. Alternatively, using your way you could use `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Replace(typeOf(IFilterProvider))` i think - off the top of my head.

Comment: Having said that, it is important to know that any `ActionFilter` you creat using the default IFilterProvider or otherwise seems to be created as a singleton by the MVC framework. This means they are not always a good choice for inject dependencies - unless the dependency itself is also a singleton. I need to update the blog with this information, so proceed with caution.

Comment: Good to know Nick, I ended up figuring out that I needed to add the IFilterProvider instance in GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services instead of GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters